# Focus the input in the WebView with React native

Tags: react-native, webview

Have you any idea to create a onFocus event in this input of the WebView ?

```
            export default class App extends Component {

             render() {

              return (

              <View style={styles.container}>

             <WebView
                 originWhitelist={['*']}
                source={{ html: ' </br></br><form> <input type="text" 
                placeholder="name" onFocus=(*****)/> <input 
                 type="text" placeholder="surname"/> <Button>Submit</Button> 
             </form>' }}  />

            </View>
                    )}}
```

I tried the usual onFocus but it doesn't work . I want to dispatch an event when i focus the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a onFocusEvent to the input of the webview we have just to deal with postMessage and onMessage . Here is the full code :

```
      let Script = `
      document.getElementById("input").addEventListener("focus", function() {  
       var data = {
      type: "OnFocusEvent",
      message : "OnFocusEvent"
     };
      window.postMessage(JSON.stringify({data}),"*");
        });
      `;

    <WebView
      style={{ flex: 1 }}
      source={{
        html:
          '</br></br></br></br><form > <input id="input" class="input" type="text" 
        placeholder="Product barcode "/></form>'
      }}
      keyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction={false} //ios
      autoFocus={true} //android
      injectedJavaScript={Script1}
      automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
      allowFileAccessFromFileURLs={true}
      scalesPageToFit={false}
      mixedContentMode={"always"}
      javaScriptEnabled={true}
      javaScriptEnabledAndroid={true}
      startInLoadingState={true}
      onMessage={event => {

      alert("You can do here whatever you want")

      }}
      onLoad={() => {}}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

There is closed [Pull Request](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/18965) for that feature. For now, you can use react-[native-enhance-webview](https://github.com/TryImpossible/react-native-enhance-webview)

I hope that helps. Good luck.

Comment: thank u i gonna see with  react-native-enhance-webview